# For loop variable undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, undefined, var

I'm working on implementing a system where elements can be dragged and dropped to create flowcharts. My **Issue** is with saving the flowchart so that it could be reloaded when needed. For now I've created a method that saves all the previous data of the element onto the final array that holds only elements that are dropped on the container. But I'm getting a **Trivial Error**  as ***Undefined variable*** on the debugging interface. Hence I'm not getting the intended output and the alert messages that I included are not being printed when the condition is met.

### Code in Context

```
function saveFlowchart()
{
    var nodes = [];
    var matches = [];
    var searchEles = document.getElementById("container").children;
    for(var i = 0; i < searchEles.length; i++) 
    {
        matches.push(searchEles[i]);
        var idOfEl = searchEles[i].id;

        if(searchEles[i].id !=null || searchEles[i].id !="")
        {
            var $element = $("#" + searchEles[i].id);
            var dropElem = $("#" + searchEles[i].id).attr('class');

            var position = $element.position();
            position.bottom = position.top + $element.height();
            position.right = position.left + $element.width();
            alert("class:"+dropElem+"\nTop position: " + position.top + "\nLeft position: " + position.left + "\nBottom position: " + position.bottom + "\nRight position: " + position.right);

            finalArray[idOfEl-1][0]= idOfEl;
            finalArray[idOfEl-1][1]= dropElem;

            var elId = parseInt(idOfEl);

            if (dropElem == "stream ui-draggable")
            {
                for(var count=0;count<100;count++)
                {
                    alert("One loop opened with count="+count);
                    if(createdImportStreamArray[count][0]==elId)
                    {
                        finalArray[elId-1][2]=  createdImportStreamArray[count][1]; //Selected Stream from Predefined Streams
                        finalArray[elId-1][3]= createdImportStreamArray[count][2]; //asName
                        alert("createdImportStreamArray[count][0]==elId");
                    }
                    else if(createdExportStreamArray[count][0]==elId)
                    {
                        finalArray[elId-1][2]= createdExportStreamArray[count][1]; //Selected Stream from Predefined Streams
                        finalArray[elId-1][3]= createdExportStreamArray[count][2]; //asName
                    }
                    else if(createdDefinedStreamArray[count][0]==elId)
                    {
                        finalArray[elId-1][2]= createdDefinedStreamArray[count][1]; //Stream Name
                        finalArray[elId-1][3]= createdDefinedStreamArray[count][4]; //Number of Attributes
                        finalArray[elId-1][4]=[];
                        for(var f=0;f<createdDefinedStreamArray[r][4];f++)
                        {
                            finalArray[elId-1][4][f][0]=createdDefinedStreamArray[count][2][f][0]; //Attribute Name
                            finalArray[elId-1][4][f][1]=createdDefinedStreamArray[count][2][f][1]; // Attribute Type
                        }
                    }
                    alert("One loop closed with count="+count);
                }
                alert("Loop ended with count="+count);
            }

            else if (dropElem == "wstream ui-draggable")
            {
                ElementType="wstream";
            }

            // else if conditions...

            alert(finalArray);
        }
    }

    //Code to output the connection details in a json format
    //The following is not affected by the above mentioned error

    $(".node").each(function (idx, elem) {
        var $elem = $(elem);
        var endpoints = jsPlumb.getEndpoints($elem.attr('id'));
        console.log('endpoints of '+$elem.attr('id'));
        console.log(endpoints);
        nodes.push({
            blockId: $elem.attr('id'),
            nodetype: $elem.attr('data-nodetype'),
            positionX: parseInt($elem.css("left"), 10),
            positionY: parseInt($elem.css("top"), 10)
        });
    });
    var connections = [];
    $.each(jsPlumb.getConnections(), function (idx, connection) {
        connections.push({
            connectionId: connection.id,
            pageSourceId: connection.sourceId,
            pageTargetId: connection.targetId
        });
    });

    var flowChart = {};
    flowChart.nodes = nodes;
    flowChart.connections = connections;
    flowChart.numberOfElements = numberOfElements;

    var flowChartJson = JSON.stringify(flowChart);
    //console.log(flowChartJson);

    $('#jsonOutput').val(flowChartJson);
}
```

### Debugging Interface

[image: Debugging Interface]

According to this the `count` variable in the for loop is undefined. I've tried taking the first statement `var count=0` outside the loop declaration part and defining it in the very beginning of the method. But that simply checks for count=0 against the conditions and doesn't increment at all.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated as I've been working on this minor error for almost 2 days now.

Comment: According to your Debugging Interface, `dropElem` is not equal to `stream ui-draggable`, so the for loop will never get executed?

Comment: @JEarls So in order to equate this, how should I convert `dropElem`?

Comment: All I can see is that `count` will be undefined because the for loop is in an `if` statement whose condition evaluates to false.  You need to figure out why the condition is that way.  For example, make sure you're actually comparing against the correct value for the `class` attribute of the html element in question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to figure it out